# variance of summation/compound variable?

Tags: variance, aggregation, sum

here is my situation. I am weighting a packet of material that has 10 individual units in it. In the end of the day I would like to know the average weight and variance of the individual units but the problem is that I cannot weight each unit individually since I would have to destroy the packet to get to the individual units. So in lieu of this, I am trying to make an inference of the individual units from what I know about the packets. I weighed 10 packets (hence I have 100 individual units). I was able to figure out the average weight of the units but am having trouble with the variance. Here is what I have done so far:

$$
\begin{split}
\bar{y}&=\frac{1}{10}\sum^{10}_{i=1}y_i\\
       &=\frac{1}{10}\sum^{10}_{i=1}  (x_{i,1}+x_{i,2}+...+x_{i,10})~~[since~y_i=x_{i,1}+x_{i,2}+...+x_{i,10}]\\
       &=\frac{1}{10}\sum^{100}_{j=1}x_j\\
       &=\frac{1}{10}(100~\bar{x})=10~\bar{x}
\end{split}
$$

thus we have the average of $x$, $\bar{x}=\frac{\bar{y}}{10}.$ But now my challenge is how to do I find variance of $x$ given the variance of $y$? Any suggestions? Thanks!

::::UPDATE::::

After some thought I came up with this reasoning:
$$
\begin{split}
\frac{1}{10}var(y)&=var(\bar{y})\\
       &=var(10~\bar{x})\\
       &=100~var(\bar{x})\\
       &=100~\frac{1}{100}var(x)~~[assuming~that~all~x~are~i.i.d.]\\
       &=var(x)
\end{split}
$$

thus we have $var(x)=\frac{1}{10}var(y).$ I am correct in that if we assume that all the individual units share the same common variance and are independent of each other, this result holds?

Comment: You need to know (or assume) more about what's going on. In some cases, the units within a packet might tend to have very similar weights; in other cases, they might often be wildly different.  Would it be possible to destroy a small representative sample of the packets in order to assess this?

Comment: Dr Huber - I do agree with you that the best way would be to destroy a small sample of the packets to assess the intra-packet variability. I was just hoping to to use mathematical statistics to come to a conclusion of some sort without destroying packets. I gave the question some more thought I have updated my original post. Your thoughts?